# Safari has some menu items that are dimmed and won't work. Is there a way to make them active?

Tags: macos, safari

I'm running High Sierra on my older iMac. I use Safari as my browser. Under several of the Safari, menu items are certain options that are dimmed out and can't be run. Specifically, under the History menu is an option to open all windows from the last session. This could come in handy but that menu item appears to not be active and clicking on it has no effect. Is there any way to use these menu items?

Comment: I don't think it has to do with the Mac's age. I'm running High Sierra on my iMac late 2015, and those Safari menu items are dimmed on my machine as well.

Comment: Does it actually re-open all your windows from the last session [without using the menu] each time you relaunch it ? That would be dependent on system prefs ? General > Close windows when quitting...

Answer (score 1):

> Safari has some menu items that are dimmed and won't work. Is there a
>   way to make them active?

Two possibilities that I can think of.

1- If you clear the history before quitting Safari, it wont be there when you restart.

[image]

2- If you have a setting in Safari to clear the history after set time.

[image]